# C++ rebuild deletes dependency files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a C++ solution taken from an undocumented opensource, which was originally a vs2008 solution but now it is a vs2012 solution.
I moved all projects from the v090 toolset to v110 toolset.
In the solution there are 2 .lib projects and one exe.
Every time I build or rebuild the exe project, it deletes the lib files and than I have a build error that it can't find those files.

What can I do? I need to work every time for about 20 minutes to get it to build, what can be fixed?

Comment: This is most likely because all of your projects are sharing the same intermediate folder. They need to be different for each project, or you'll get conflicts. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, go to General, and change the path for the "Intermediate Directory". Make sure to change this for all configurations (Debug *and* Release, which should also be different).

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up on the project long ago and don't even have the PC anymore, so I can't test your answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well that might mean that there is a problem with the linker. Try add those lib files to the linker.
You can find the linker usually by clicking right click on your project and then going to properties.
You will find a menu and on the left side. Just open the linker, and then open the "Input".
In the first line you probably find "additional dependancies". Add your lib files over there by name + format.
And also keep the actual lib files in your Driver:\VisualStudio\VC\lib folder.
I hope that helps! :)

Comment: That is how it is defined to use those .lib files, but still it deletes the files when starting to rebuild and than gives an error that the files are missing

Comment: Well two questions then...what type of libs are they and also,have you made these settings true for debbug and release as well?

Comment: what do you mean what type of libs? it creates a .lib file. yes all settings are done both in debug and release

Comment: Well i mean there are system libs,know library add ons or self made libs...truely i dont know why it gets deleted.... is it deleted completely from your pc?

Comment: yes, so I started making copies at other places and copy it again after it is deleted

Comment: Ok so in that case,try and go to your properties again and then config properties and general. Make sure that under the extenstions to delete on clean you dont have the .lib maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Sorry but no, I dont have .lib there